# Problem with configure and build php 5.2 on redhat 5

Tags: rhel, mysql, php

I downloaded php binaries and tried to build the same using following command.

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-mysql
```

But i'm getting the error related to mysql client library.

```
checking for MySQL support... yes 
checking for specified location of the MySQL UNIX socket... no
checking for MySQL UNIX socket location... /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
configure: error: Cannot find MySQL header files under yes.
Note that the MySQL client library is not bundled anymore!
```

I confirmed that I have mysql client installed.

```
$ yum list mysql*
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
Installed Packages
MySQL-client-community.x86_64    5.1.48-1.rhel5   installed
MySQL-server-community.x86_64    5.1.48-1.rhel5   installed
```

Answer (score 1):

For *building* stuff you need the `-devel` packages too, the plain packages just contain runtime.

Why are you trying to build PHP? What do you think is wrong with the package provides by the ditribution? The *version* might be old, but I can assure you it has (backports of) all the security patches.

Comment: Well, i had php 5.1, but one of the new applications needs php 5.2. So, I first removed 5.1 version (yum remove php*). Then downloaded php 5.2 binaries from php.net and simply followed the process given on their website for configuring PHP with Apache 2.x and mysql support. MySQL version is 5.1.48-community. Also, I am not sure which -devel packege is required to be installed. Please help.

Comment: What requires PHP 5.2? Not an official package...

Comment: a perticular web application requires PHP 5.2 only ...

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot of pages on Google i have figured it out that i need to install mysql-devel package

`$ rpm -ivh MySQL-devel-community-5.1.48-1.rhel5.i386.rpm`

This created required header files under /usr/include/mysql

Then i executed command : 
`$ ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-mysql-dir=/usr/`

It resolved the error.